# List the orbits and the normal subgroups of the group $D_7$ acting on itself

Tags: group-theory

Consider $D_7$ the dihedral group acting on itself by conjugation. List the orbits and the normal subgroups of the group.

Usually when the group has few elements, I list all the possible subgroups and draw a multiplication table. I know it is doable in this case but is there a more general way to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal subgroups of $D_n$ are classified in general. A possible standard reference here are the notes of [K. Conrad](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi3yq3OzcLJAhUE2hoKHapMCZMQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fdihedral2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNExft8iJ2-3luuioMN8NO5LaOhJVg&sig2=9PYFSYK-b-wdMejDkDkeNQ&bvm=bv.108538919,d.d2s). The classification of all normal subgroups is given in Theorem $3.8$. In particular, for $n$ odd, there is at most one normal subgroup per index. All normal subgroups are given then by the
subgroups $\langle r^d\rangle$ with $d\mid n$,  and have index $2d$. 
In section $3$ the author lists all subgroups of $D_n$ and then collects them into conjugacy classes of subgroups (the orbits under conjugation).