# Group contains elements $a$ and $b$ of order 4 and 2 and $a^{3}b=ba$. Determine order of element $ab$

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose a group contains elements $a$ and $b$ of order 4 and 2 and $a^{3}b=ba$. I have to determine order of element $ab$.

I tried hard to do algebraic manipulations but i couldnot do it. Is their a fixed way for these type of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that algebraic manipulation and some trial and error work well for these types of problems. You are given:

$$a^{-1}b=ba$$

Then $(ba)^2=(ba)(ba) = (ba)(a^{-1}b) = b^2=e$. Then what do you know about the relationship between $|ab|$ and $|ba|$?

Comment: Are they equal always?

Comment: yes. this is a handy tool to have, try and prove it

Comment: It seems you knew that order of ba is 2. What if we didnot know
?

Comment: I did not assume that, I calculated $(ba)^2$ to see what the outcome would be

Answer (score 6):

We have $(ab)^2=a(ba)b=a(a^3b)b=b^2=1$ and $ab\neq 1$. Hence $ab$ has order $2$. The group generated by $a$, $b$ with $a^4=b^2=1$ and $a^3b=ba$ is the dihedral group $D_4$.

Comment: Where can i get information about Dihedral group?

Comment: Hi @TaylorTed, for dihedral group references see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559890/list-the-orbits-and-the-normal-subgroups-of-the-group-d7-acting-on-itself/1559899#1559899).

Answer (score 2):

$a^3b=ba\Rightarrow a^3=bab$ because of $o(b)=2$, because of $o(a)=4$ then $(ab)^2=abab=1$ so because of $ab\neq1$ you have $o(ab)=2)$ Am I wrong?